# Clear out contents in NSMutableData

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutabledata

I am new to Swift and iOS Development.
How do we clear an `NSMutableData` without using release and then re-alloc/init again to be used again?

I have tried `resetBytesInRange()` but that replaces the contents by zero.

I tried `data.length = 0`, but there is garbage data at the end after appending.

`data.setData(nil)` gives an error.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890778/how-do-we-clear-out-contents-in-nsmutabledata) but it doesn't solve my problem on swift.

Please help.

Comment: `data.length = 0` *does* clear the contents of the NSData object. Can you show a concrete example where this does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `setData()` with `NSData()`:

```
mytableData.setData(NSData())
```

Answer (score -1):

For Swift create new data object for current data will replace old bytes with empty bytes.

```
data = NSData(data: NSData())
println(data)
```

For mutable data:

```
mutableData = NSMutableData(data: NSMutableData())
println(mutableData)
```

**Output:** Empty bytes array

```
<>
```

Comment: The question is about mutating `NSMutableData`.

Comment: `mutableData = NSMutableData(data: NSMutableData())` replaces the `NSMutableData`. This might not be the behaviour if you have multiple references to this `NSMutableData`.

Comment: OP wants `nil NSMutableData` that will also affect multiple references.

Comment: @Kirsteins: What you think this for down vote? Where you find this will make multiple references. Give me an explanation.

Comment: If you have multiple references pointing to the same object as variable `data` and you assign new object to `data` the other references will point to different object. In your case you are not mutating, but replacing.